# BackgroundDownloadAsync doesn't start and hangs

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, onedrive

One of my users reported that he cannot download a file from OneDrive with my app (WP8.1 WinRT). I'm using [LiveConnectClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.live.liveconnectclient.aspx) to connect with the cloud.

The strange thing is that the credentials are ok, hence he seens folders, which I get with:

```cs
LiveOperationResult opResult = await clientOnedrive.GetAsync(folder.Path + "/files");
```

so it's not the problem with connection or other. But when I try to download a file:

```cs
StorageFile tempFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(Uri.EscapeUriString(fileName), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
// path has /content at the end -> file.something23479283/content
LiveDownloadOperationResult result = await clientOnedrive.BackgroundDownloadAsync(path, tempFile, ct, liveProgress);
```

[the operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219347.aspx) *awaits* without result for ever. Though the phone doesn't hang as it's asynchronous and the user is able to cancel the download with cancellation token `ct`.

When I debug the app, or use release version it works perfect. Other users also don't report any problems.

Does anybody have an idea what can happen? Are there any preferences I'm missing?

---

I must say that I'm also a bit lost in which method I should use in my case: [LiveConnectClient.BackgroundDownloadAsync(String, IStorageFile, CancellationToken, IProgress) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219347.aspx) says (btw: it's working fine except the case mentioned above):

> Note  Windows Phone doesn't support this method.

contrary [LiveConnectClient.BackgroundDownloadAsync(String, Uri) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219338.aspx) says:

> Note  Windows Store apps do not support this method.

So which method should I use in *Window Phone Store App* (WP8.1 WinRT)?

Comment: Can the user download the file content directly from onedrive.com?

Comment: @BradCleaver Good question. It will be hard to find now, as the user said few hours ago that now he is able to download files. I've tried also to to create *LiveDownloadOperation* first and then to *StartAsync()* it, but that also didn't help. From the log file obtained from the user I've seen that in fact there was a problem. Nice riddle. It seems that the cause has been *somehow* on user's/his phone/his client side, but it's hard to say how, and therefore replicate the problem.